# How do I alter summary attributes from long-text-with-summary, like help text, number of form rows, and label?

Tags: theming, forms, entities

How can I change* the number of rows "Summary" gets displayed with on forms (from Long Text with Summary data type), or alter its label or help text? These are settable for the "Long Text" part, but not for its corresponding summary, if you choose to enable it.

*Properly, not with js ;)

Comment: So, I basically decided that creating an alter hook for this this was silly, and simply created a "Summary" textarea field of my own for users -- Drupal's default functionality required too many usability sacrifices.

I'm hiding the summary in Full Content view and using Views Conditional to decide to display summary vs body in views. Easy, elegant, simple. Still curious about an answer to this, but my solution seems like a decent workaround and won't be confusing to future site admins, either.

Comment: (Alternatively, I could use a teaser showing the custom summary field and use the content display-style in Views. That's easier in many ways, and is best practice, but it just doesn't work well for the specific thing we're doing. But that's how I'd recommend others do it.)